# Angularfire & google analytics setup

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire

i'm trying to setup Google Analytics as part of AngularFire package, with no success so far.

what I've tried so far:

in app.module.ts -

```
import { provideFirebaseApp, getApp, initializeApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { getAnalytics, provideAnalytics } from '@angular/fire/analytics';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LayoutComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    UiSharedModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    provideAnalytics(() => getAnalytics()),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

in app.component.ts -

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'myAwesomeApp';
  // private analytics: Analytics = inject(Analytics); -- none of the injection attempts are working

  constructor(private analytics: Analytics) {
    // console.log(this.analytics.app.automaticDataCollectionEnabled); -- throws error - ERROR FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call initializeApp() first (app/no-app).

this.analytics.logEvent("some_event", {..}) - not exists anymore, any idea how i can use it?
    
  }

}
```

I'm using Angular 16, and angular/fire - ^7.6.1

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to import `logEvent` from analytics and run that independently

```
import { Component, inject } from '@angular/core';

import { Analytics, logEvent } from '@angular/fire/analytics';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  private analytics: Analytics = inject(Analytics);
  
  constructor() {
    logEvent(this.analytics, 'event_name')
  }
}
```